# Any way to override the default Camel FatalFallbackErrorHandler?

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-camel

Is there any way to override the default Apache Camel [FatalFallbackErrorHandler](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/FatalFallbackErrorHandler.html)?

As the class documentation states, it's purpose is as "an ErrorHandler used as a safe fallback when processing by other error handlers such as the OnExceptionDefinition." Indeed, this is exactly the scenario I'd like to handle, except instead of the FatalFallbackErrorHandler's simple logging, I'd like to pass the message to an activemq endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not. It gets very complicated if nested error handlers triggers, which can also lead to circular looping etc.